# Render Razor Code inside HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razorengine

I have some HTML that is saved on my DB, this is later modified and saved on a variable and finally it's printed on my view using `@Html.Raw( Model.Page.Html )`.

The problem is, this HTML possess some `Razor` codes like `ViewBag.Email`. How could i render this Razor code before printing the HTML ? I have already tried to put that on an `Partial View` and call it inside the HTML and then print it but it also won't work.

Some people pointed me the `RazorEngine` lib but i couldn't make that work, i installed the version 3.7.7 but the documentation is a little confusing for me.

If `RazorEngine` is my best option could anyone please include an example of how to render my HTML before printing it ?

**EDIT**

This is an example of my problem: My contact page has a form inside. At some point in my `Filter` i checked to see if the request was from a mobile device and with this information i would set the type of the input on a ViewBag, for example:

```
<input type="@ViewBag.ITEmail" placeholder="E-mail" name="cEmail">
```

This HTML is fetched from my DB and passed to my Helpers to modify some information and then it's printed on my `View` using `@Html.Raw( Model.Page.Html )`.

Comment: @MuratYıldız, My problem isn't with the HTML itself but with the Razor sintax that resides inside my HTML. I'm going to update my question with an example.

Comment: I think the best solution is to keep trying with RazorEngine but don't use ViewBag, use a model.

Comment: @ZippyV, i could indeed use a Model but my problem is that i still couldn't figure out how to implement the RazorEngine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor views are dynamically built. Every time you edit your razor file it is compiled in background and built into new dll.

Basically you would have to trigger build process somehow that is normally triggered when cshtml file is changed. So, you would have to do that. Load and save a file. Or dig deep into internals...

Comment: I'm not saving the HTML in a physical file, i have the HTML saved on my Database and then i get the HTML as a string and print it on the `View` using `Html.Raw( "<div>My name is @ViewBag.MyName</div>" )`. Them problem is that the `View` prints `<div>My name is @ViewBag.MyName</div>` instead of `<div>My name is Terkhos</div>`

Comment: I understand that you don't saving to a physical file. I'm saying that you have to do that in order to trigger build process. That's just how asp.net mvc works.

Comment: I got it now, the thing is that i have already looked into that i couldn't figure out how to do it. The best option i think i have is the RazorEngine but i can't find my way into the implementation.